# If crossing over did not occur, would pairs of cells after meiosis II have the same genes?

Tags: genetics, chromosome, meiosis, cell-division

If crossing over did not occur, would there be two pairs of cells with the same chromosomes after meiosis II? This question came to my mind while I was reading through my bio textbook. After meiosis I, there are two cells with 1n chromosomes but the chromosomes have 2 chromatids. It seems to me that, if crossing over didn't occur the chromatids of the chromosomes would be identical and after meiosis II the 2 cells would divide into 2 pairs of cells with identical chromosomes. Is this right?

Comment: Your understanding is correct.

After meiosis II, you will have 4 cells: Cells 1 and 2 are identical and each have one haploid set of chromosomes; Cells 3 and 4 are identical and each have the other haploid set of chromosomes. These two sets of chromosomes are mutually exclusive. Note that these sets of chromosomes are not [necessarily] the same as the gametes that formed the organism.